# Continue to load webapp even if one spring bean initialization fails

Tags: java, spring

So if spring initialization fails in a webapp then the webapp itself does not come up. To prevent this, I can probably not re-throw any exception from my code for that specific bean initialization and the webapp will continue to load, right?

Is there any other way to tell to spring not to fail the webapp itself on particular bean initialization failure?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Presumably you have code that requires/assumes that your beans are properly initialized.  If so then why allow the server to start in a broken state?

Comment: @aroth I realize you asked this nearly a decade ago, but this just came up for me; a business requirement that literally said "we need the core of the app to start up and work even if part of a fringe part of the app is in a broken state". It's a long story, and the merits are open to debate, but it's a requirement that may occasionally come up.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Continue to load webapp even if one spring bean initialization fails

AFAIK, you can't do this.

> I do multiple DNS lookups on start up. I do not want the webapp to fail if one of them fails.

In that case, you need to modify your bean(s) to handle the case where the DNS lookup fails, leaving the bean instance in a state where it is essentially inactive but harmless, or where it can retry the DNS lookup later on.

In short, you have to cope with this yourself.

Answer (score 3):

Have attribute `lazy-init="true"` in that bean and every dependant bean. [Link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init) for more details.

Comment: The link the above mentioned document for Spring 3.2.x is [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-lazy-init)

Answer (score 0):

why would you do this?  If your spring context is not correct, something is seriously wrong and there *will* be issues.  The correct way to deal with this is to fix the application context.

Comment: I do multiple dns lookups on start up. The class which does dns lookup is defined as spring bean. I do not want the webapp to fail if one of them fails.