# Continue on fail Spring bean initialization

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I having a Spring bean that needs to load OpenCV native library, but I also want if it failed to load, then application still boot successfully. I've already catch exception but Spring still throw exception out and shut down application. Why Spring is throwing exception in my catch block and how can I make Spring ignore exception on initlaization? I found 1 related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920672) but it's quite old and haven't had any solution yet.

My code looks like this.

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  private boolean isLoaded = false;

  public MyService() {
    try {
      OpencvLoader.loadShared(); // load native library here
      isLoaded = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOGGER.error("Load failed");
    }
  }
}
```

Stacktrace

```
Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fptu.swp.ppr.cv.service.ObjectDetectionService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:885)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:789)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fptu.swp.ppr.cv.service.ObjectDetectionService]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1312)
    ... 46 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.fptu.swp.ppr.cv.utils.OpenCVLoader$SharedLoader.getInstance(OpenCVLoader.java:95)
    at com.fptu.swp.ppr.cv.utils.OpenCVLoader.loadShared(OpenCVLoader.java:27)
    at com.fptu.swp.ppr.cv.service.ObjectDetectionService.<init>(ObjectDetectionService.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:204)
    ... 48 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.fptu.swp.ppr.cv.utils.OpenCVLoader$SharedLoader.<init>(OpenCVLoader.java:55)
    at com.fptu.swp.ppr.cv.utils.OpenCVLoader$SharedLoader.<init>(OpenCVLoader.java:33)
    at com.fptu.swp.ppr.cv.utils.OpenCVLoader$SharedLoader$Holder.<clinit>(OpenCVLoader.java:91)
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the loader throws an `Error`, and you catch all `Exception`s.

You can catch `Error`, but this is usually not advisable. I doubt it is in this case, you should probably look into another solution.